# How can I show meeting end hour in the calendar pane in Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-outlook-2016

From what I remember, in Office 2010, it was showing both meeting start time AND meeting end time. Now it only shows the start time. Help? :)

[image: Office Calendar pane on the right]

This is how I enable showing the To Do Bar:

[image]

Comment: You are talking about the `Task View` from the Inbox, not the calendar (judging from the screen shot)? Obviously 2016 is different than 2010. What have you tried in order to change the view to the way you prefer?

Comment: Added an extra screenshot, does it answer your question?